# Can a DTFT have a period different of $2\pi$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I think almost everything is in the title.

In an exercise, a DTFT is given :
$$X(e^{j\Omega}) = \sin(\Omega) + \cos(\Omega/2)$$
The period of this DTFT is $4\pi$. Is that possible? I mean, the definition of the DTFT shows that it is $2\pi$-periodic
$$X(e^{j\Omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x[n]e^{-k\Omega n}.$$

I don't know if a $4\pi$-periodic DTFT has any sense. I'm really confused about this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It doesn't look like that map is well defined since it depends on how you represent the number, since $\exp(j\Omega)=\exp(j\Omega+2j\pi)$ but $X$ gives two different values. Is there a restriction on $\Omega$? or should it just be $X(\Omega)$?

Comment: Also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform

Comment: No restriction given on $\Omega$ , $\Omega$ is here defined as $\omega/T_s$ where $T_s$ is the sampling period of the discrete time signal $x[n]$. Defining the DTFT as $X(e^{j\Omega})$ instead of $X(\Omega)$ is just a small trick to show explicitly the $2\pi$-periodicity, but there is no difference with the notation you suggested.

Comment: When you evaluate the function, isn't the domain of $\Omega$ restricted to $[-\pi,\pi)$ radians per sample? Outside of this domain are replicas, so I don't see how it could be, as you say, $4\pi$-periodic.

Comment: I totally agree that with this restriction on $\Omega$, my problem disappears. But the exercise does not give this restriction... But does this DTFT has any sense without the restriction you just give?

Comment: The restriction comes from the definition of the DTFT. You can evaluate it outside of $[-\pi, \pi)$ but you will get the same result. The specific DTFT you have is fine, it's just not $4\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was confused but things are becoming clearer in my head now. I thought the $2\pi$-periodicity of the DTFT was just a kind of ``property'', but it's more like an intrinsic result of his definition. Is it possible  to indicate that your comment answers my question? (sorry I'm new to stackexchange).

Comment: Don't worry about it, but you can answer your own question if you want. It might help to cement things in your head, too.